# How do I convert all vector elements to NA (no condition)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame

```
school<-c("NYU", "BYU", "USC")
state<-c("NY","UT","CA")
measure<-c("MSAT","MSAT","GPA")
score<-c(500, 490, 2.9)
score2<-(c(200, 280, 4.3))
df<-data.frame(school,state, measure,score,score2,  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> df
  school state measure score score2
1    NYU    NY    MSAT 500.0  200.0
2    BYU    UT    MSAT 490.0  280.0
3    USC    CA     GPA   2.9    4.3
```

And I would like to set all the values for certain columns to NA without any condition. Just set them to NA. i.e.

```
> df
  school state measure score score2
1    NYU    NA    MSAT NA    NA  
2    BYU    NA    MSAT NA    NA
3    USC    NA     GPA NA    NA
```

I have tried:

```
df <- mutate_at(vars(-school,-measure),na_if(.,!is.na(.)))
```

Where I was expecting `na_if(.,!is.na(.))` to convert any value that wasn't already NA to NA. But as you can see I'm not correctly feeding the columns into the `is.na()` function.

```
Error in length_x %in% c(1L, n) : object '.' not found
```

How would I go about achieving this. I have many more columns I would like the perform this on than columns I want to preserve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're asking specifically for `mutate`, here are some things to consider:

1. In your line `df <- mutate_at(vars(-school,-measure),na_if(.,!is.na(.)))`, it fails because it expects `df` as *the first argument* - or piped in. The correct usage would be

   `df <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(-school,-measure),na_if(.,!is.na(.)))`

But that doesn't solve it, because

2. Have you checked what `na_if` and `is.na` does? Just a quick `?na_if`?? Because it doesn't replace values when the second argument is true, but replaces values equal to the second argument with `NA`. So, that just plainly doesn't work as expected.

And finally,

3. Why only change non-NA values to NA? Why not just change *everything* to NA?

Which leads to the following solution:

```
just.na <- function(x) rep(NA, length(x))
df %>% mutate_at(vars(-school, -measure), just.na)
```

Or, an anonymous function:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(-school, -measure), ~rep(NA, length(.)))
```

Or, it turns out you can do this:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(-school, -measure), ~NA)
```

(I am equally surprised!)

Comment: thanks for this - that last one is so simple!

Answer (score 4):

This would do it

```
df[,c("state","score","score2")]<-NA
```

Comment: You can omit the first comma. Also, it is recommended to add space on both sides of `<-`.

Comment: This works thank you. I guess my only comment would be that in the post I mentioned I have many more columns where I want to convert to NA than columns I'd like to preserve, so I wouldn't want to type all the column names (there are 10's of them) and I was using dplyr because I wanted to avoid writing 1 or 2 lines just to get a vector of all columns I wanted to change and then use %in%.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df[,c(2,4,5)] <- NA
```

Comment: as I don't like typing too many column names I also go often with this solutions. Anyway, if the colums of the input change, you will be surprised which ones are set to NA. To save my typing I go dput(names(df))) which gives me a nice character vector of all col names and I just have to keep the ones I want (deleting the others manually).